# What I am doing wrong here - dynamic problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

You are about to go shopping for some candy in a local store. They sell candy for either $1 or $2 pieces. You would like to know in how many unique ways you can purchase candy based on the amount of money you have.

```
def buying_candy(amount_of_money):

    if amount_of_money < 2:
        return 1

    dp = {0: 1, 1: 1}
    x = 1
    while x < amount_of_money:
        if x not in dp:
            dp[x] = 1
        dp[x] = dp[x] + dp[x - 1]

        x += 1

    return dp[amount_of_money - 1]
```

`print(buying_candy(4))`

OUTPUT: 5

EXPLANATION:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2
2 + 1 + 1
1 + 2 + 1
1 + 1 + 2
```

UPDATE:

SOLUTION of Problem

```
def buying_candy(amount_of_money):

    if amount_of_money < 2:
        return 1
    
    dp = {
        0: 1,
        1: 1
    }
    x = 2
    while x < amount_of_money + 1:
        if x not in dp:
            dp[x] = 1
        dp[x] = dp[x - 1] + dp[x - 2]

        x += 1
    
    return dp[amount_of_money]
```

Comment: Before anything else: Are you sure `2+1+1` and `1+2+1` are supposed to be considered different solutions? They both represent the same composition of candies.

Comment: @Orius both are different composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This problem does not require dynamic programming. Denote the amount of money by *n*. There are between 0 and ⌊*n*/2⌋ twos. If the number of twos is *k*, then the number of ones is *n*−2*k*, and the total number of ones and twos is *n*-2*k*+*k* = *n*-*k*. Each solution with *k* twos corresponds to choosing *k* out of the *n*-*k* positions for the twos. So the total number of solutions with *k* twos is (*n*-*k* choose *k*), and the total number of solutions is the sum of this expression over *k* from 0 and ⌊*n*/2⌋.

   In Python:

   ```
   import math
   n = 4 # amount of money
   total = sum(math.comb(n-k,k) for k in range(n//2+1)) # total number of solutions
   print(total)
   ```
2. If the rules of the game require using dynamic programming, here is a correct version:

   ```
   def buying_candies(n):
       if n < 2:
           return 1
       dp = [1, 1] # use list instead of dictionary, as keys are 0,1,2,...
       for i in range(2, n+1):
           dp.append(dp[i-1] + dp[i-2])
       return dp[n]

   print(buying_candies(4))
   ```
3. It is all just Fibonacci sequence, in fact :)

   So there is in fact a closed formula.